# TS Cannot find name ''

Tags: typescript, promise

I'm a complete beginner in typescript and I've been stuck quite a while on this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Most of this code comes from the webpart development tutorial of Microsoft SharePoint.

I'm trying to return a variable yet I keep getting the "Cannot find name" error with the line  `return response;`

```
private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
client
  .api('/users')
  .get((err, res) => {
     console.log(err);
     var response = res
   });
return response;}

  private _renderListAsync(): void {
  this._getListData()
    .then((response) => {
     this._renderList(response.value);
  });}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `_getListData()` method return type is defined `Promise`, but it isn't return `Promise`, also your `.api()` and `.get` are asynchronous that's why it can't find `response` variable, an option that you can do here is to return `Promise`

```
     private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          client
            .api('/users')
            .get((err, res) => {
              console.log(err);
              resolve(res);
            });
        });
      }
```

Comment: Adding return before the new promise made it work. Thank you very much.

Comment: ah yeah I forgot to add it :)